# Why does this op-amp circuit show current flowing like that?

Tags: operational-amplifier, kirchhoffs-laws, nodal-analysis, equation

This image shows an op-amp being powered. Is there any reason why it shows current flowing from the negative side of the bottom battery into the op-amp or why it shows current flowing from the positive end of the top battery into the op-amp? It can either be using conventional or real current flow, so why is it drawn like this?

Also, this was followed by this equation: \$i_0=i_1+i_2+i_++i_-\$

It doesn't make any sense, because current can't flow out of the minus side of a battery in conventional and can't flow out of the positive side in un-conventional.

[image]

Comment: The current can be a negative number.

Comment: Analysis101 - Hi, When a post copies or adapts material (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be [correctly referenced](/help/referencing). For online content, the source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked as a minimum (see the rule about references for offline books / articles). Therefore please [edit] your question to add the appropriate source reference (i.e. source name & link) for that image, and remember to include references in future. || I see the required reference is also missing from the copied image in your [previous question](/q/697289).

Comment: Random image from unidentified textbook.  We have no context for the image.  Please identify the image source.  Are you reading to much into a simplistic drawing describing powering the op amp?  i1 and i2 are probably very low due to op-amp being high impedance.

Answer (score 6):

> is there any reason why it shows current flowing from the negative side of the bottom battery into the op-amp or why its showing current flowing from the positive end of top battery into the op-amp?

The diagram does not show that current flows one way or the other.

It only establishes the reference direction for each current.

An arrow pointing in to the op-amp means "this current will be considered positive when it flows into the op-amp and negative when it flows out of the op-amp".

It is very likely that upon solving the circuit you will find that \$i_-\$ is negative, indicating that the actual direction of current flow is out of the op-amp.

Answer (score 4):

> *why is it drawn like this*

Both the **current direction arrow** and the actual **sign of the current** need to be taken into account when establishing the true direction of current. Generally, the picture and the formula are correct and, because you have assumed a positive value of \$i_-\$ is flowing into pin 4, you are mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

If those arrows were meant to indicate the actual direction of movement of charges, then I agree, the diagram is quite misleading. Sticking with conventional current, as we should always do, you're correct, the arrow for \$i_-\$ is not pointing in a direction that positive (conventional) charges could ever flow, unless something unusual is happening.

The arrows, then, are not a consistent indicator of actual charge movement. Rather they establish an convention, for this schematic only, of how the *sign* of the labelled currents should be interpreted.

The value of \$i_-\$, for instance, will always be negative (again, unless something weird is going on), since positive charges at node (pin) 4 will be moving towards the most negative potential. A negative value implies a conventional positive current flowing in a direction opposite to the arrow. This means that from an algebraic perspective, the arrow can never have a "wrong" direction, which is why I'll repeatedly put the word "wrong" in quotation marks. The actual direction of charge flow is determined by *both* arrow direction *and* the sign of the value of \$i\$. In isolation, neither arrow nor quantity are meaningful, but *together* they resolve any ambiguity.

That might be all you need to know, but I want to give some examples.

This has big consequences for \$i_0\$, \$i_1\$ and \$i_2\$. Their arrow directions *must not* be interpreted as actual charge movement, because the potential of those nodes can change, and at any instant in time charges could be leaving or entering the op-amp, depending on potential, and depending on how they are connected to the rest of the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxzOWR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the left, OA1's output is always *sourcing* conventional current, because potential \$V_{OUT1}\$ is always greater than −12V, the potential of the other side of its load R1. Algebraically:

$$ I_{OUT} = \frac{(V_{OUT1}) - (-12V)}{R_1} $$

Consequently, \$I_{OUT}\$ is always positive, and its arrow actually does represent the direction that positive charges would flow.

The output of OA2, in contrast, is always *sinking* current. That is, positive charges will always flow *into* that output, since \$V_{OUT2}\$ is always less than the potential at the top of R2. You might think that the arrow must be pointing the wrong way, but here we have an opportunity to see that it's fine. Let's do a formal, careful algebraic analysis.

For any resistor, conventional current enters the terminal with the higher potential, and leaves the lower potential end. And yet here we seem to have a contradiction; We know that conventional current is flowing downwards through R2, from +12V towards the always-lower potential \$V_{OUT2}\$, and the arrow direction is obviously "wrong".

For the moment I'll completely ignore the +12V, and call that node "A" instead. When I apply Ohm's law here, I will not assume knowledge of \$V_A\$, I will simply stick to the convention I just described, that current always enters the higher potential end of a resistor. That means according to the labelled arrow direction, \$V_{OUT2}\$ is assumed to have the higher potential, and the voltage \$V_{R2}\$ across R2 is calculated accordingly:

$$ V_{R2} = V_{OUT2} - V_A $$

Then apply Ohm's law:

$$ I_{OUT2} = \frac{V_{R2}}{R_2} = \frac{V_{OUT2} - V_A}{R_2} $$

We can then plug some numbers into that equation to test it. Let's say that OA2's output is \$V_{OUT2} = +6V \$, and we know the supply potential at A is \$V_A=+12V\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{OUT2} &= \frac{V_{OUT2} - V_A}{R_2} \\ \\
&= \frac{(+6V) - (+12V)}{1k\Omega} \\ \\
&= \frac{-6V}{1k\Omega} \\ \\
&= -6mA
\end{aligned}
$$

That negative sign is telling us that in reality, +6mA flows *into* the op-amp. The op-amp is sinking current, not sourcing as the arrow would suggest. Don't trust the arrow, trust the combination of arrow *and* sign.

Crucially, even though the arrow direction is "wrong", the algebra *always* works out, provided we are careful with voltage polarities.

For the last circuit on the right, it might be immediately clear that current direction could be to the left, or to the right, depending on \$V_{OUT3}\$, and so it might not make sense to set that direction in stone by drawing an arrow on the diagram. However, it's paper, and we have to draw an arrow, so I just *guessed* current direction (to the right). That's perfectly OK. Again, let's apply Ohm's law, taking care with the polarity of voltage across R3. Current is annotated to be downwards through R3, so our algebra must reflect that, by assuming OUT3 has the higher potential. The voltage across R3 is:

$$ V_{R3} = V_{OUT3} - 0V = V_{OUT3} $$

Ohm's law:

$$ I_{OUT3} = \frac{V_{R3}}{R_3} = \frac{V_{OUT3}}{R_2} $$

Let's evaluate that last equation with two possible output potentials, \$V_{OUT3} = +6V\$ and \$V_{OUT3} = -6V\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{OUT3} &= \frac{+6V}{1k\Omega} \\ \\
&= +6mA
\end{aligned}
$$

That tells us that conventional current is indeed to the right, *out* of the op-amp, and downwards through R3.

Now let's try with \$V_{OUT3} = -6V\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{OUT3} &= \frac{-6V}{1k\Omega} \\ \\
&= -6mA
\end{aligned}
$$

This time we have conventional current to the left, in opposition to the arrow. But strictly speaking, the arrow isn't really wrong. The combination of arrow and sign tell the whole story, which is *always* correct, even if you initially guessed the arrow direction incorrectly, but you must take care to specify potential differences across elements *according to your annotated current directions*.

Getting back to your original question, the author applied Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL) to all the currents entering and leaving the op-amp. The law states that the sum of currents entering must be equal to the sum of currents leaving (otherwise you have a leak somewhere), and that's clearly represented in his/her equation.

With what you now know about the importance of the signs, it's pretty clear that \$i_-\$ will have to be negative for that equation to be true, but it *is* still true.

All that just to say: arrow direction alone tells you nothing. Sign of the quantity alone tells you half the story. Only taken together do you have the whole picture.